# How to hide relevent div when relevent button is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a dynamic div's which needed to hide when relevant delete button clicked. This divs also have dynamic id's. i want to hide relevant div where button is clicked. im only getting the first div id all the time. Im new to jQuery can someone please help.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".reBox").click(function() {
    alert($('.reBox').attr('id'));
      // $(this).hide(); 
});
});

<div class="boxx" id="<?php echo $tot_meal; ?>">
  <div class="reBox" id="<?php echo $tot_meal; ?>">
     <img src="../images/error.png" width="16px" height="16px" />
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Right now this will always select the first div with the class `reBox`, try with `alert($(this).attr('id'));`, this would return only the clicked div.

Comment: how do you know you're getting the first div all the time?
I'm not really a php guy but it looks like class `boxx` and `rebox` have the same id, so your alert would always be the same wouldn't it?

Comment: @ I Can Has Cheezburger : thanks for your idea after getting the id i was able to make it work.. @Mark F : Even the id's were same i have used two different classes, therefore i was able to get the ids of the particular class which im calling... Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have dynamic elements, try [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```
$(document).on('click', ".reBox", function () {
    console.log(this.id);
    $(this).hide();
    //if you want to close boxx
    // $(this).closest('.boxx').hide();
});
```

Comment: :Thanks, i was able to get ID properly. its working now

Answer (score 1):

As you have dynamic html elements use [`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/). Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".boxx").on('click','.reBox',(function() {
      $(this).hide(); //to hide reBox
      $(this).parent("div.boxx").hide(); //to hide boxx element
});
});
```

Comment: :Thanks, i was able to get ID properly